# Is there any to get user unique identity after authentication process of MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

Currently, I am using the Microsoft OneNote API (REST) to read the content of OneNote Pages. I have already subscribed for the notifications on the event of any changes happens in any page's content. Microsoft so sends me a notification for every change in the content of any page. They send a combination of`X-Authenticated` `user_id` and subscription ID in the webhook. Like this:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "subscriptionId": "WLID-00000000441A2E0C",
      "userId": "WLID-1F50AB22CBE04E58"
    }
  ]
}
```

Recently, MS released the Graph API and recommended to use this one instead of the OneNote API. SO, I am migrating my implementation from OneNote API to Graph API.

I was getting `userId` (`WLID-1F50AB22CBE04E58`) with `X-Authenticated-userId` in the headers of the response of one of this API in OneNote API

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/notebooks
```

But, I am not getting this with Microsoft Graph. There should be a unique identity for each user who is completing the Authentication process.

Where will I get `userId` from Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication isn't handled by Microsoft Graph, it's handled by Azure Active Directory. You can get additional user information using OpenID Connect by requesting the scopes `openid`, `email`, and `profile`.

You can also get the current user's profile by calling the [`/me`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`).

Webhook [Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0) also return a `creatorId` which will be the `id` for the authenticated user that created the subscription.